# How to debug your application with root permissions on VSCODE?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, .net-core, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug dotnet core web app, however it's not possible to do it without having root permissions.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Permission denied'
```

The naive approach would be launching VSCode with root permissions, which is generally not a recommended (and I would like to avoid it).

Is there any way to configure `launch.json` to execute the debugger with root permissions?

I've tried already creating a pre-launch task executing `sudo` or `sudo su` commands.
I tried running the application and trying to attach to the process (also got declined because of insufficient permissions)

Comment: Such socket exceptions usually occur when you want to bind to a reserved port (<1024). Why cannot you use a port like 5000? Alternatively you can run vsdbg as root, while VSCode attaches to vsdbg via socket.

Comment: Thanks man, binding to port 5000 worked indeed.
Just for my curiosity - how to run vsdbg as root? Is it achievable via `launch.json` or `tasks.json`?

Comment: Yeah, while the comment helps, it doesn't answer the root question: How to run vscode for .NET Core as root. I'm facing the same issue. Brand new project and it's a showstopper...

Answer (score 2):

For C#:

1. Locate vsdbg-ui (in my case: ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.17/.debugger)
2. Rename "vsdbg-ui" to "vsdbg-ui2"
3. Create a new file in the same folder called "vsdbg-ui" with following content:

   pkexec [yourhomefolder]/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.17/.debugger/vsdbg-ui2
4. Make the new file "vsdbg-ui" executable
5. Launch the debugging session in VSCode. You will get a prompt to enter your sudo password. You are debugging with sudo now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This indeed helped to launch debugging as sudo for .net project.